# WebService is an httplistener or TcpListener?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find which is the best solution for me for creating an API web service.
The only thing I need is to send a string from a remote device, and server to answers me just with Error or OK.
What is the best solution I should use? Http listener or Tcp Listener. I'm interested to use c# language. I don't know if there are more solutions. I need something quick and easy. Also, my software to be light and fast. What about ASP.Net?

Here is my example, I found for a Http listener:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.0.214:8282/");
listener.Start();

new Thread(() =>
{


Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
           while (true)
           {


               HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
               string methodName = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Url);
               //MessageBox.Show(methodName);
               string Response = "Response";

               HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
               string responseString = Convert.ToString(Response);
               byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
               response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
               System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
               output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
               output.Close();
               //MessageBox.Show(methodName);
           }
       }).Start();
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend considering a .Net Core Web API.  Rolling your own network server isn't as easy as it seems on the surface.

Comment: You may look at [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/). It is a daugther of [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/).

Comment: What language is need for this?

Comment: Nancy is on C#, Sinatra is on Ruby

Comment: What is wrong if i will create an api application with http listener?Performance?